# How to add a new job to a view in jenkins via python-jenkins?

Tags: python, jenkins

New Job can be created using `create_job()` API and new view can be created using `create_view()` API. But how can I add the new job that is created to the new view?

I am referring to https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your view using `reconfig_view()` as described [here](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.reconfig_view)

Comment: Okay, Just wanted to check if there is anyother api available to add just the job to the view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method for creating a job in view. To add job in view is necessary get view XML and add job name in tag "string".