# Jobs are not visible in new Jenkins view

Tags: jenkins

We have created couple of jobs under different different project acronym, which is visible in ***All*** the tabs on jenkisn dashboard. But it is not coming for the corresponding views.
e.g.

- aat-CWM-fe-APP_MAIN_MAVEN-snapshot should come under aat
- kps-MVW-be-kps-online-snapshot should come under kps

I tried to search in SO, but did not get any much help. Please consider this as my scrolling time and provide the solution.

Some of the question , I have gone through for help:

- [Jenkins restrict view of jobs per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323129/jenkins-restrict-view-of-jobs-per-user)
- [How to tell if UIViewController's view is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777438/how-to-tell-if-uiviewcontrollers-view-is-visible)
- [How to add a new job to a view in jenkins via python-jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133367/how-to-add-a-new-job-to-a-view-in-jenkins-via-python-jenkins)

Comment: please check n confirm , which view is created.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know, Jobs will not be visible in newly created Jenkins tab/view because of these two reasons:

1. You might have created other than List View like Dashboard view or Nested View.
2. You might not have selected the checkbox "Show standard Jenkins
   list at the top of the page " under Dashboard Portlets

So, the resolution will be :

1. Create a list view, as dashboard view is more of a consolidated view to any job.
2. Select the checkbox "Show standard Jenkins list at the top of the page " under Dashboard Portlets.

If any other reasons are there, someone please update.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I created list view and afterwards I was able to see list of jobs under it :)

Comment: Toggling the "Show standard Jenkins list at the top of the page" checkbox worked for me. I assumed this would be already implied but that's what I get for assuming ‍♀️.